# Unexpected functionality working on Subscribing Redis channel in python

Tags: python, redis, socket.io, reactive-programming, python-asyncio

I'm new to manipulate connection with Redis server in python. I'm wondering that is there any way to figure out the situation below:

What I'm doing is

```
There are three mainly step for my program:
1. subscribe channel on Redis
2. Get the message from Redis and convert to custom model(or dict)
3. Sent the custom model to my server using socketio
```

What I write is

```
async def subscribeRedisChannel():
    for item in r.subscriber.listen():
        logger.info("[DEBUG]Checkin Result from Redis: {}".format(item))
        if item['type'] == 'message':
            checkInSubject.on_next(item)
            await sio.emit('punchByEquipment', data = keep.value)
```

Environment

```
python3
socketio
asyncio
rx
redis
```

The problem I faced

```
if I call the subscribeRedisChannel function in my main function, the program will be hang on it. Other program cannot work correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

> For those people who have the same or similar issues.

In this problem, I realize that the mainly issues is using blocking message. At he begin I follow the OLD-VERSION example code to implement the connection mechanism between redis and my program

```
 for message in p.listen():
     # do something with the message
```

However, you can directly call  `get_message()` to listen the channel in non-blocking mechanism. For the usage example, you can find it in the [test code](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/a404ad3dee93b3b0deb90b4075fd28734d78a282/tests/test_pubsub.py)

```
 while True:
     message = p.get_message()
     if message:
         # do something with the message
     time.sleep(0.001)  # be nice to the system :)
```

If you are looking for the specific explanation, check this answer in other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871526/is-non-blocking-redis-pubsub-possible).